# js fetch with TS, is not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Why I get this warning in TS ?

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'PokemonList'.ts(2322)
```

This error is on line: "return e"

Code:

```
export interface PokemonList {
  count: number;
  next: string;
  previous?: any;
  results: {
    name: string;
    url: string;
  }[]
};


const PokeApi = async (): Promise<PokemonList> => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10');
    return res.json()
  } catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
};
```

If I make this:

```
( Promise<PokemonList> | unknown )
```

then I get this error:

```
The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<unknown>'?ts(
```

Comment: try `( Promise<PokemonList | unknown >)`

Comment: `} catch(e) { return e; }`  Not a good idea, doing this you have now broken your promise chain.  IOW: You can no no longer do -> `try { PokeApi(); } catch { ... }`, and you would be forced to check the error manually...  Just take out the `try / catch`, it's not required.

Comment: @Keith then what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of that function is

```
Promise<PokemonList | Error>
```

As Keith said, this is "Not a good idea, doing this you have now broken your promise chain.". Promises have `.catch` and work in `try/catch` to chain Promises together. What you have you require an `if(/else)` check, which is not what Promises are meant for.

To fix this, you should remove the try/catch block inside the function and just handle errors with `catch` whenever you call it.

```
const PokeApi = async (): Promise<PokemonList> => {
  const res = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10');
  return res.json()
};

// when calling it inside async function

let pokemonList: PokemonList;
try {
  pokemonList = await PokeApi();
} catch (e) {
  // Handle error
}
```